Azure Data Migration Tool error on validate; A window handle must be configured (MsalClientException)
I am in the process of migrating an Onprem Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 to an Azure DevOps Service and I am following the Data Migration Tool for Azure DevOps Migration Guide.
I am running the migrate from the same machine having the running DevOps server, running Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.
I have a setup Azure Entra which I am specifying in the command and I am logged on to the source machine with an account which has permissions to create an organisation. Identities are synced with domain through Azure AD Connect.
During the first step, the validate, I am executing the Migrate command as follows.
Migrator.exe validate /collection:"http://localhost:8080/tfs/{Collection}" /region:{region} /output:"C:\temp" /tenantdomainname:{name}

The error I am receiving is A window handle must be configured. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-wam#parent-window-handles (type MsalClientException)
Pasting the log file result below.
[Info   @15:44:03.314] [Info] Data migration tool for Azure DevOps version 19.225.34715.1
                       [Info] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
                       [Info] Executing at 2024-04-02T13:43:59.8879578Z:
                       [Info] Migrator.exe  validate /collection:**{}** /region:**{}** /output:"C:\temp" /tenantdomainname:**{}**
                       [Info] Connection string not specified, trying to use the one from the Application Tier's web.config
                       [Info] Using the framework connection **{}**
                       [Info] The database type is Configuration
                       [Info] The database service level is Dev19.M225.3
                       [Info] Azure DevOps Server version Dev19.M225.3
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Loading Validations
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Identities, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Import.IdentityImportValidation)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Build Identities and Scopes, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityImport.BuildImportValidation)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Populate License Information, (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Deploy.Application.LicenseImportValidation)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Project Status, (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Deploy.TFCollection.DataImport.ValidateProjectStatus)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Project Names, (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Deploy.TFCollection.DataImport.ValidateProjectNames)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Collection Database collation, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud.ValidateDatabaseCollation)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Database Milestone, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud.ValidateDatabaseTfsVersion)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Collection Database Usage, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud.ValidateDatabaseUsage)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Properties Were Loaded, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud.ValidatePropertiesWereLoaded)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Collection Database Size, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Cloud.ValidateDatabaseSize)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Minimum Supported TfsMigrator version, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.Extensions.ValidateMinTfsMigratorVersion)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate File Content Migration Job, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.Extensions.ValidateFileContentMigrationJob)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate File Content Consistency, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.Extensions.ValidateFileServiceConsistency)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Single Partition, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.Extensions.ValidateSinglePartition)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate TFVC files are in File Service, (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DataImport.Extensions.ValidateTfvcInFileService)
[Info   @15:44:03.314] Validate Project Processes, (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.PlugIns.DataImport.ProcessMapImportValidator)
[Info   @15:44:03.330] Value of extended property TFS_DATAIMPORT_COLLECTIONID=**{}**
[Info   @15:44:03.345] Executing Microsoft Graph Request
[Error  @15:44:04.991] Encountered an unexpected exception. Retry will not be attempted. CurrentRetryCount: 0, RemainingRetries: 5, Exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.Types.AadGraphServiceException: Request failed with exception ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: A window handle must be configured. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-wam#parent-window-handles
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Features.RuntimeBroker.RuntimeBroker.<AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Broker.BrokerInteractiveRequestComponent.<FetchTokensAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<FetchTokensFromBrokerAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<GetTokenResponseAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadClient.ActiveDirectoryClientBuilder.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadClient.ActiveDirectoryClientBuilder.BuildClient()
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadGraphService.BuildGraphClient(AadServiceRequestContext requestContext)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadGraphService.<GetTenant>d__1.MoveNext()
                          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ExecuteGraphRequest>g__executeRequest|1()
                          at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.BackoffRetryManager.Invoke(Action action)
[Error  @15:44:05.007] Exception Message: Request failed with exception (type AadGraphServiceException)
                       Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ExecuteGraphRequest>g__executeRequest|1()
                          at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.BackoffRetryManager.Invoke(Action action)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.ExecuteGraphRequest[T](Func`2 request)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.GetAadTenantId()
                          at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.PopulateDataImportPropertiesOnContext()
                          at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.PopulateValidationItems(DataImportValidationContext context)
                          at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunValidations(Boolean requireNetwork, Boolean validateFiles)
                          at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunImpl()
                          at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommand.Run()
                       Inner Exception Details:
                       Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
                       Exception Stack Trace: 
                       Inner Exception Details:
                       Exception Message: A window handle must be configured. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-wam#parent-window-handles (type MsalClientException)
                       Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Features.RuntimeBroker.RuntimeBroker.<AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Broker.BrokerInteractiveRequestComponent.<FetchTokensAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<FetchTokensFromBrokerAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<GetTokenResponseAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadClient.ActiveDirectoryClientBuilder.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadClient.ActiveDirectoryClientBuilder.BuildClient()
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadGraphService.BuildGraphClient(AadServiceRequestContext requestContext)
                          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Plugins.DataImport.AadGraphService.<GetTenant>d__1.MoveNext()
[Info   @15:44:05.007] Execution Time: 0:00:05.1723274
[Info   @15:44:05.007] Output Folder:  C:\temp\Logs\**{}**\20240402_154403


Seems that the process is searching for a window handle to prompt for a username but is failing during "Microsoft Graph Request"?
Any ideas?
DevOps Server is running on the machine as I have tried to input an invalid collection. This resulted in a different error.
I have tried running command on cmd as admin / current user / and through powershell.
I have also tried using the az command in powershell, after authenticating with Connect-AzAccount

Hi there, Dose the user who signs-in the server machine and runs the migrator validate command, have the permissions to connect to both the TFS configuration and collection databases? Can you please use the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console User to sign-in the server machine and run the same command for a test? In addition to the error captured from the DataMigrationTool.log, have you checked the logs in other files under the path C:\temp\Logs\**{}**\20240402_154403 and see if there is any other specific error?

Besides, as far as I tested, the migrator validate command didn't require az login. Can you please check if the tenantdomainname like domainName.com is a verified domain in your AAD?

Hi Alvin, Thank you for your reply. My account is an Azure DevOps Server Administrator, and there are no further logs under the output log folder, only the one I have pasted in my question.

Hi @JeromeSciortino, may I know if the issue is resolved if you use the older version of the DataMigrationTool? Thx for your time and sharing.

Hi Alvin, thanks again for your assistance. I can confirm that I have managed to pass the validate step with the previous version provided in the answer below.

Glad to know the issue is mitigated from your side and thank you very much for your taking time to report the issue and sharing the update. Cheers!

The previous version has been re-uploaded on Download Center while we are addressing the bug found. Thanks for reporting this to us!

can you provide  a link to the resource

Of course! https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=54274

I am seeing the same error today 04/03/2024.
I used an older version yesterday and the migration worked.
Today I was testing the most recent version of the ADO migration tool DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2022.1_19.225.27309233 that was released on 3/29/2024.
This is a bug in the new version of the ADO migration tool.

I just verified that I was able to run the migration tool that was released around Feb 2024 and the older version migration tool completes the Migrator prepare command.
DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2022.1_19.225.23248967

Thanks for your post. Would you be able to point me to a download link of that specific version "DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2022.1_19.225.23248967"?

The Microsoft download page only has the most recent version of the Data Migration Tool.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=54274
